# Media Element.js - Change video poster image

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I have integrated MediaElement.js video player into my MVC 4 application.In that view, I have a button and in button click I want to change the video source and poster image. I have found prperties to change the video source on button click from the code provided in mediaelementjs.com. But it doesn't contain any property to change the poster image. Is it possible to change poster image like video source?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="videoplayer">    
            <video width="436" height="331" id="player2" poster="../../Images/pix.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">

            <!-- MP4 source must come first for iOS -->
            <source type="video/mp4" src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/videos/video2.mp4" />

            <!-- Fallback flash player for no-HTML5 browsers with JavaScript turned off -->
                <object width="436" height="331" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../build/flashmediaelement.swf">        
                    <param name="movie" value="../build/flashmediaelement.swf" /> 
                    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/videos/video2.mp4" />         
                    <!-- Image fall back for non-HTML5 browser with JavaScript turned off and no Flash player installed -->
                    <img src="../../Images/pix.jpg" width="436" height="331" alt="No video playback capabilities" 
                        title="No video playback capabilities" />
                </object>   
            </video>
        </div>
        <script>

            $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
                success: function (player, node) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
                }
            });

    </script>

    <input type="button" id="changevideo" value="Change Video" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#changevideo').click(function () {
            $('video, audio').each(function () {
                $(this)[0].player.setSrc("http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/videos/video1.mp4");
                $(this)[0].player.play();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#changeposter').click(function() {
    $('video, audio').each(function() {
        $(this).attr("poster", "../../Images/new_pix.jpg");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to reload the player after you changed poster in order to take effect.

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#your-player-element-id');
player.load();
player.play();
player.pause();
```